# restrict the style to first level elements

Tags: html, css

I am using following style and html code for listing some items

```
li.DC a > ins.jstree-icon{
height:22px; width:350px; border:#999999 1px solid; margin-bottom:2px; list-style:none; background-color:red;
```

}

```
<li class="DC">
    <a><ins class="jstree-icon"></ins>HelloName</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a><ins class="jstree-icon"></ins>HelloName</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I want to apply the style to first level occurrence of jstree-icon, right now the style is getting applied to the 2nd level also. Can any one suggest the CSS for the same ?

Comment: Have you tried `li.DC > a > ins.jstree-icon`?

Comment: Just tried , working fine. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the selector place

Your selector is saying first class name of the `a` tag (which is not valid) but what you need is first `a` tag of the `li`.

```
li.DC > a ins.jstree-icon{
    height:22px; width:350px; border:#999999 1px solid; margin-bottom:2px; list-style:none; background-color:red;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R87Un/)**